# CakePHP: Find records from last hour

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I spent a good amount of time last night scouring the internet trying to find a solution to finding all of the records created from the last hour in the MySQL database. The one answer I found which is posted everywhere doesn't even work..

This is what I've come up with based on what I found online and thought might work:

```
$recentUploads = $this->Upload->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('Upload.created LIKE' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour')))
        ));
```

But still no luck at all. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want records where the timestamp is greater than or equal to the time 1 hour ago:

```
$recentUploads = $this->Upload->find(
  'all',
  array(
    'conditions' => array(
      'Upload.created >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'))
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something really minuscule :\ Thanks so much, it works perfectly!

Comment: how would you do less than or equal to 1 hour? (lol, nvm, didn't notice the >=)

Answer (score 0):

you need this function for any time you want to use :

```
function SinceDate($timebyminuites)
{

$to_time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$from_time = $timebyminuites*60;
return date('Y-m-d H:i:s',round(abs($to_time - $from_time),2));
}
```

when you want get the datetime from one hours ago 
you can use the function like this :

```
$onehoursago = SinceDate(60);
```

and the query will be like this :

```
select * from Upload where Upload.created >= '$onehoursago'
```

Comment: Isn't `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` effectively `time()`?